# Matlab: How can I change comment's shortcut to `ctrl+/`?

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I want to change `comment`, `uncomment`, and `wrap comments` all using `ctrl+/`, like in most `IDE`s. How can I do that?

I can change `Matlab`'s shortcut for comment to `ctrl+/`
[image]

But shortcut for `uncomment` and `wrap comments` require different key combinations.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't

Comment: @Ratbert And I think so. I'm just wondering why `matlab` would favor such a non-conventional approach. It's really annoying.

Comment: @cqcn1991 have you considered some external application to write a keyboard macro?

Comment: Did you try [EditorMacro](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24615-editormacro-assign-a-macro-to-a-keyboard-key-stroke-in-the-matlab-editor-and-command-window)? Might be helpful...